# Mutating arrays in a nested Swift struct

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift, so I appreciate any feedback or suggestions on my approach. For reference, I'm using Xcode 12.1 and Swift 5.3. Essentially, I have a series of `struct`s, one of which has an array of strings. What I'd like to do, is to append a string to that array. Consider the following code:

```
struct Collection {
    var things: [Thing] = []
    
    mutating func add(_ thing: Thing) {
        things.append(thing)
    }
}

struct Thing {
    var messages: [String] = []

    mutating func add(_ message: String) {
        messages.append(message)
    }
}

var collection = Collection()
collection.add(Thing())
var thing = collection.things.first
thing!.add("test")


print(collection.things.first!.messages.count)
```

I was expecting the final line to print `1`, but instead it prints `0`! The compile does not display any errors either. If I change the code so that `struct Thing` is `class Thing` and drop the `mutating` keyword from its `add` method, then the code works.

Having said that, I don't understand why my original code does not work as I would expect. I'm able to append a `Thing` instance to `Collection`, but not a string to that same `Thing` instance after the fact.

Have I misunderstood how the `mutating` keyword works?

Comment: `collection.things[0].add("test")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would get your expected `1` if you did:

```
print(thing!.messages.count)
```

because you have added the `"test"` to `thing.messages`, not `collection.things.first!.messages`.

"Now hold on a second!" I hear you say, "I just said `var thing = collection.things.first` on the previous line! How come adding to `thing.messages` doesn't imply adding to `collection.things.first!.messages`?".

This is because structs have value semantics. When you do `var thing = collection.things.first`, you are saying "copy the value of `collection.things.first` to a variable called `thing`". You are **not** saying "the variable `thing` now *refers* to the same thing as `collection.things.first`". To say that, `Thing` has to be a reference type (`class`).

So now you have two copies of the same value, one in `thing` and one in `collection.things.first`. You change the copy stored in `thing`. The other copy is unaffected.